# Getting error on like operator in ASP.NET with SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am using a code to get the city name with like keyword but not showing any result

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(tempPath);
 con.Open();

 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 10 City from tbl_City where City like @Name+'%'", con);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", prefixText);

 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 da.Fill(dt);
```

Can anyone give a solution to this issue?

Comment: Which error? BTW did you add % to prefixText in C# instead of on SQL code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way of addin `LIKE` in parameterized quer is first change :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 10 City from tbl_City where City like @Name+'%'", con);
```

To :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 10 City from tbl_City where City like @Name", con);
```

And then change this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", prefixText);
```

to :

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", prefixText + "%");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(tempPath);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 10 City from tbl_City where City like '"+ prefix+"%'", con);
     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: keep in mind that adding the argument directly in the query is a bad practice and makes code vulnarable to attacks (SQL injections for example)